# Is it still bad practice to build a website that relies on javascript?

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, compatibility

Is it still bad practice to create a website that relies on javascript?

I know it used to be, but nowadays most browsers support them...  Why or why not should I worry about this?

Comment: Given the recent development of `node.js`, 37signals is developing a new framework http://daringfireball.net/linked/2010/11/08/37signals-mobile-framework ... I'd say Javascript will only become more popular and important.

Comment: @ohho How prevalent JavaScript has become on the serverside or in the general coding community has absolutely no bearing on if it's good practice or not to use it in browser. Lua is now reasonably prevalent, but that doesn't mean if one browser decided to implement it that it's okay to use.

Comment: Although browsers support it, roughly 3% of users disable JS (security, ad-blocking, performance reasons). The content you are serving should be readable without JS.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Depends on the target audience, but more importantly *how* you're using JavaScript.

Using it for effects that don't interfere with any actual functionality is usually fine.

If you want to target a broad audience and your website is non-functional without JavaScript, then you may want to reconsider.

Comment: I gave a +1 because while JavaScript can do lots of nice things -- and perhaps should be required for a "RIA"-site or similar, it really isn't nice when *everything just "doesn't work"* because JavaScript is disabled. It should degrade gracefully -- even if that means displaying a chunk of text saying "ooh, you can't use this portion of the site" (hopefully the portions can be isolated out).

Comment: @Jamie Wong - how about Facebook? Probably the biggest audience in the world and they require JS.

Comment: (Full disclosure - I was an intern at Facebook.) @JM4: That's a valid point. Facebook does require JS, mostly out of pragmatism. The kind of interactions they're trying to enable on their site are nearly impossible without JS, and making them work is mostly a waste of their developer resources. That said, their mobile site (m.facebook.com) does work without JavaScript - and it suggests you go there instead if it detects you don't have JavaScript enabled. So the core parts of the Facebook service are still usable without JavaScript.

Answer (score 11):

Spending extra effort to make a site work without Javascript is becoming increasingly ridiculous when so much of the web breaks when you disable it.

For example, did you know that you can't install Google Chrome when you're using a browser without Javascript?  Their "accept and install" button requires Javascript.

[image]

You should, of course, use the `<noscript>` tag to display appropriate messages to the user that may have accidentally disabled Javascript in their browser.  Google places this text at the top of their page via the noscript tag:

> You need a JavaScript-capable browser
>   to download this software. [Click here for instructions](http://www.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=23852&hl=en) on how to enable
>   JavaScript in your browser.

I admit this was a surprising case when I discovered it, because well... it's Google.  And millions of people have downloaded Chrome.  But I think it illustrates the point that a site dependent on Javascript is a pretty normal thing today.

Answer (score 4):

No modern, interesting, web application does *not* use JavaScript. A content-only site might not use it, and any web site should warn the user that JavaScript is required, but it's been a long time since "no JavaScript" made any sense.

Answer (score 1):

Search engines still do not evaluate JavaScript.  If you want your site to be indexed, all the content needs to be accessible without JavaScript.

Comment: Well... this isn't _exactly_ true anymore. See: http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/

Comment: this surely depends on the site. If the site is about the content, then JavaScript can be irrelevant. If the site performs actual work, then indexing is less of an issue.

Comment: @JamieWong It is not just search engines ... it's also other developers that need to extract data automatically, Wikipedia is a good example, try writing a program that parse Wikipedia that need Javascript to work vs just plan html Wikipedia

Answer (score 1):

It's not bad practice to rely on JavaScript, but I would say it's bad practice to assume without checking that JavaScript is enabled.

At the very least your website should give the user a nice error if JavaScript is disabled. Ideally, at least the basic functionality (such as text content and images) should still work and JavaScript should enhance it: see [Unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript).

Answer (score 0):

You should know your target audience of course.  If you know that everybody will be using a certain browser for something like an intranet application then you can probably assume that they will be using JavaScript.

If you are writing an application for the general public, then I would take extra effort to write it such that it works without JavaScript.  Then use JavaScript to enhance the existing solution.  It takes extra effort, but you can make an application both accessible and interesting if you try.

EDIT: Also thought I would add since I haven't seen any references to it, but building a website that relies on straight JavaScript (and not a common JavaScript library like JQuery) would be unwise.  JQuery helps you address some of the browser differences that made JavaScript so problematic a few years back (not to mention doing more with less code).

Comment: Building a site that does not rely on a general purpose JavaScript library like jQuery is perfectly reasonable and not unwise.

Answer (score 0):

The new [HTML5 standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/), which many browsers are already starting to support, relies pretty heavily on scripting for much of its new APIs.  So no, it is not bad practice to use scripting, it is encouraged.

Comment: At present, using HTML 5 is bad practice, because it is so little supported.

Comment: This answer is irrelevant anyway. HTML5 merely standardizes the capabilities of existing browsers. It does not recommend a particular approach to web development.

Answer (score 0):

If you're making a website that's available on the internet and whose audience is more than just people you know, then it's absolutely not OK to build it so that it doesn't work without JavaScript. Many people and corporations choose to browse the web with JavaScript turned off, for many reasons, and you need to remember that the majority of users are not developers and do not browse the web in the same way with the same tools as you.

Use [progressive enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement): start by creating and testing all the core functions of your site with simple HTML. When that works, add JavaScript functionality.

Developing a highly interactive web application is a different matter. For that, it's not unreasonable to insist on your users using particular browsers with JavaScript enabled.